# Ideas on how to fix a void at the bottom edge of my concrete steps?

Tags: concrete, stairs

I was recently pulling weeds and I noticed that there is a hole at the bottom of my  concrete stoop.  I'm not quite sure on how to address it.  I'm pretty handy so I'm sure that this can be tackled without professional help (and prices).  Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

[image: Stoop]
[image: Hole 1]
[image: Hole 2]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not a hole. That's just the bottom. Steps like this are poured on the dirt, and while the dirt level probably should have been flatter and lower (for aesthetic reasons), this isn't a structural flaw.

Attempting to patch it will make things worse, visually speaking. Put some mulch over the bottom edge or raise the soil level a bit and be happy.

Comment: agreed, hiding unsightly edges is exactly what shrubbery is for!

Comment: This makes sense.  I will put some dirt over it and plant something to hide it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Plant grass!  Just get a section of sod (dirt plus grass) and plant.

Comment: An oddly specific landscaping suggestion, but sure. :)

Answer (score 1):

If that was mine, it would bug me every time I saw it. I would dig it out a bit, cut a piece of plywood to act as a forming piece, stuff in a little gravel and pack in some concrete in two stages, using the plywood as a form and a few bricks to hold it in place. Good luck!

Comment: And that would all fall apart inside two years. Vinyl patch might hold longer, but either is going to look like a patch until it breaks loose again.

Comment: @isherwood  I did one on a bay window slab in /around 1985 and it's still holding. Maybe just lucky.